# How to increment a string by .i in Java?

Tags: java

My goal is to add value pairs to a `HashMap` and if a value is already taken it will increment the previous value by .i. What I mean by this is it would start as `0.1` ... `0.9` then `0.10`, `0.11`, `0.12` and so on...

I have started:

```
for (int i=0; i < 50; i++){
    Double test = Double.parseDouble( 0 + "." + i);
```

But I cannot find a suitable test to add a decimal place onto the double once it has reached .9 (0.9, 0.10) Everything that I've tried doesn't work reliably. I was wondering if anyone could help.

Comment: floating point has NOT "reliable decimal digits"

Comment: floating point arithmetic is notoriously inaccurate due to the nature of computing decimals in binary. I would suggest scaling everything up x100 and storing your data as `int`

Comment: The problem with your logic is: what is `i`? `0.9 -> 0.10` suggests `i = 0.1` but `0.10 -> 0.11` suggests `i = 0.01`. If your values actually are integers, i.e. 1 ... 9, 10, 11 etc., then please state so in your question - as well as why you prepend those with `0.`.

Comment: If you want to count, you should use counting numbers: Integers. Counting with floating point numbers in a custom order is a bad idea.

Comment: Just use integers and a scaling factor, basically as you are doing now. What's wrong with your current approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I mean by this is it would start as 0.1...0.9 then 0.10, 0.11,0.12 and so on...

To print this pattern, there simplest solution is to print the value as it really a String operation rather than a mathematical one.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) 
    System.out.println("0." + i);
```

NOTE: For `double` the value `0.1 == 0.10` and there is no way to tell them apart.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DecimalFormat` to get two decimal digits. The ".00" in the parameter tells the formatter to use two decimal places while the "#" means to display the whole number as it is

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    for(int i=0;i < 50 ;i++){
        Double test = Double.parseDouble( 0 + "." + i);
        System.out.println(df.format(test));
```

Output:

```
.00
.10
.20
.30
.40
.50
.60
.70
.80
.90
.10
.11
.12
.13
.14
.15
.16
.17
.18
.19
.20
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
double division = 1.0;
for(int i=0;i < 50 ;i++){
    if (i%10 == 0)
        division *= 10;

    Double test = i/division;
    System.out.print(test + " ");
}
```

It will have duplicate each time it goes down one decimal, but I hope for testing it should be ok.